# SpringMvc tiles how to add css files

Tags: java, css, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

In my project I am using SpringMVC with tiles..

Here, I have

```
src--
     |--main
     |--resource----|--css--style.css
     |--webapp--|--WEB-INF----|jsp--here I have jsp files
                |--index.jsp
```

I want to add **style.css** to a jsp file in **/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/layout.jsp** file..

I have Tried below:--

```
    <?xml  version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.1.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.1.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.1.xsd">

        <context:annotation-config />
        <mvc:annotation-driven />
        <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.my.news" />
        <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**"  location="/resources/" />


        <bean id="viewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
            <property name="viewClass">
                <value>
                    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
                </value>
            </property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
            <property name="definitions">
                <list>
                    <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
                </list>
            </property>

        in my **layout.jsp**    I edited like 
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="WEB-INF/css/style.css" />" /> --%>

<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">

        </bean>
</beans>
```

In my **layout.jsp** ..I include the file as:--

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
```

but I am not getting the **style.css** styles..why?????please suggest me..I have tried a lot from google..But nothing executed..
[image]

I am getting **layout.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">


<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

 <spring:url value="/resources/css/style.css" var="styleCss"/>    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${styleCss}"> 





<title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" ignore="true" /></title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td height="30" colspan="2"><tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="250"><tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" /></td>
        <td width="350"><tiles:insertAttribute name="body" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="30" colspan="2"><tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

this view..but **style.css** is not working here...
this is **style.css**

```
 body {
        background:#f9ebae;
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size:11px;
        line-height:14px;
        color:#5e5e5e;
    }
```

what I want :-
[image]

what I [image]am getting;--

Comment: First of all your `location` should be prefixed with `classpath:` second you should use an absolute and not a relative URL. For thus use the URL tag (spring or the jstl one).

Comment: @ M. Deinum,Sorry Sir, I Cant understand..Can you give the example?

Comment: What part don't you undertstand?

Comment: "First of all your location should be prefixed with classpath: second you should use an absolute and not a relative URL. For thus use the URL tag (spring or the jstl one)." this one..so,what I have to do?